# How do i connect multiple buttons to one outlet?

Tags: objective-c, iboutlet

I need to connect several buttons to one IBOutlet. The first one connects fine but I go to the next button and connect it and the first button is no longer connected to the outlet.

Comment: How can you have multiple buttons on one outlet? You need an outlet per control.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able in the IB to do the following:

1. Drag a `UIButton` to your `UIViewController`.
2. `Ctrl + click` from the button to the `viewcontroller.m` file to create the `IBOutlet`
3. Copy and paste as many buttons you want to be connected to that `IBOutlet` from the IB.

That's it, if doesn't work remove the button and start from the first step,

Hope it helps.